# How to programmatically change the gridview row in EDIT mode not based on the row number

Tags: asp.net, gridview, row, edit, mode

I an looking for a way to change asp.net gridview row in EDIT mode based on primary key of the data and not based on the row number clicked on the gridview.

What are the options.

Comment: I have tried a code as below but it not helping.

protected void Row_Editing(object sender, GridViewEditArgs e) 
{
  myGridView.EditItemIndex = e.EditItemIndex; 
  BindData(); 
}

the above does it based on the row index of the gridview but i want to set the edit mode based on the primary key data bound column of the gridview.
The reason is that while clicking on the EDIT button lets i checked on row #2 but since Edit itself does the postback and refreshes the data from database the #2 may not have some other data what was deleted to be edited.

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably have a hidden column in the GridView that contains the PK.  When the edit button is clicked, you can use the appropriate handler to get the PK from that row and manipulate it as you see fit.

Update: After reading your comment, it's not that you can't get the PK, it's that the data has been refreshed between when the button is clicked and when the gridview is re-rendered as editable.  In your scenario, a user could click the third row to edit and suddenly it becomes the seventh row because other users have inserted four rows.

The simple answer is don't do that!  For one, it'll make your life a lot harder and 2) it'll be confusing for a user if they clicked the third row to edit and suddenly it's the seventh row on their screen.

If for whatever reason you MUST refresh the data, do it after the user commits their changes.  If you need to refresh the data to make sure that some other user didn't edit the values before the user updates them, well, you're going to have to find another solution.  maybe a parent/detail screen would work or add a pop-up that says that the data has been changed.  (Remember that if the values suddenly change without warning that the user will be confused as well.)

Comment: I have set DataKeyNames in gridview with primary key of data and fetching it using DataKey of row for which Edit is clicked in handler GridView1_RowEditing but whatever row index set Edit mode always shows up for row i initially clicked for edit.

I am facing a problem where by database get updated (rows getting added or deleted) and since click on edit does postback and it refreshes data on gridview, it may change the row number of data i clicked earlier and edit mode happen based on row number i clicked and it lands up showing edit mode for wrong row

Comment: Thanks for prompt reply!
In my scenario the data will never to updated, rows will only be inserted or deleted in database back.

Currently, I have select command for the gridview in HTML and even if I do not refresh the data in postback it still does it on edit... i guess it's because i have select command for gridview... i think i should programmatically bind the data and then control the postback  edit click.

Comment: No, you'd still have the same issue if rows were deleted (or if the PK wasn't an auto-incrementing value).

Comment: If there is no updating going on behind the scenes, cancel that refresh and you should be ok.  I like writing my select statements and not having them tied to commands so that I have a bit more control over it, but post your code anyway - we might have a simple fix

Comment: I believe you are suggesting as below... but no luck. Edit click still take the row number i clicked instead.

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            BindData();
        }
    }

    protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
        BindData();
    }

Comment: First, lose the `DataBind()` in the GridView1_RowEditing method so that it doesn't refresh the data.  Second, the EditIndex is *always* going to give you the ordinal for the row, so you'll have to use that number to get the primary key which you'll need to have in a hidden column in the GridView.